# Redis deployment in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, redis, kubernetes-statefulset, kubernetes-deployment

I am trying to run a Redis cluster on Kubernetes. I am not planning to persist any Redis data to the disk. Is it possible to run the Redis cluster as Kubernetes deployment and not as a stateful set?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, though I would probably still use StatefulSet specifically for the features to ensure only one pod starts at a time.

Comment: Thanks, but why do we need this feature i.e. only one pod starting at a time? Shouldn't we be having multiple pods running for HA and load balancing ?

Comment: Yes, multiple will be running, StatefulSets just make sure that it starts one at a time so you don't get a stampeding herd problem trying to join the cluster all at once.

Comment: All the examples available are showing Redis cluster being deployed as a combination of Kubernetes’ StatefulSets and PersistentVolumes. It makes sense also as each Redis instance relies on a configuration file that keeps track of other cluster instances and their roles. Are you aware of any example where we have deployed Redis in a cluster using deployment controller ?

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible to persist data in PVC with stateful sets, however in helm chart for HA redis cluster they are using stateful sets only :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 6379
      name: redis
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: redis
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis  
  serviceName: redis
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis 
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: redis
          image: redislabs/redis
          args: ["--requirepass", "admin", "--appendonly", "yes", "--save", "900", "1", "--save", "30", "2"]
          ports:
            - containerPort: 6379
              name: redis
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: .50
              memory: 1500Mi
            requests:
              cpu: .25
              memory: 1024Mi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: redis-volume
              mountPath: /data
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: redis-volume
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 20Gi
```

Comment: Yes, I saw the helm chart and hence the question. Why do we need stateful sets ? Why can't we just use deployment controller and run a stateless deployment ?

Comment: i hope you have an idea regarding stateless and stateful application. when the application is not storing anything in memory or in volume you can use stateless deployment however stateful use when the application is storing anything in memory so it always make sure the replicas start after one terminate properly.

Comment: Agreed, but in my case  I am not using any persistent volume and I am OK to loose my in-memory data. Why should I still define a Stateful set for Redis ?